# Procesar eventos con un sólo toString();

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

> Buenas. Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en generar diversos tipos de eventos y generar un toString() que indique una descripción de lo que generó el evento. Supuse que al implementar las diversas interfaces podría crear una variable de mi clase para alojar los diferentes eventos y llamar al toString() de mi clase pero he advertido que el tipo de la interfaz y el del evento que se maneja no es el mismo con lo que mi variable no funciona. Pregunta: hay alguna forma de procesar diferentes eventos con un sólo String?
>   Ahí está la pequeña chapucilla que intentaba...(Generador es mi clase y gen la variable de ella)

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    gen=(Generador)e.getSource();
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand()+""+gen.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método toString es un método de la clase Object, el cual es heredado, como sabrás, por todas las clases. Y al instanciarlas, por todos los objetos que puedas fabricar con java.

Algunas clases sobre-escriben este método para incluir los valores de las distintas variables de clase. Pero si no son sobre-escritas, lo que devuelve el método toString, es la clase del objeto seguido de una arroba y el código hascode del objeto. El código hascode es un código identificador de la posición de memoria en la que se almacena el objeto.

Para sobre-escribir el método toString debes de hacerlo mediante un método público, que devuelva un String y cuyo nombre sea toString, sin parámetros.

```
public String toString(){
  return "Cualquier String procedente de valor como esta cadena de texto
  o procedente de variables String o casteadas a String";
}
```

Y luego ya depende de qué es lo que quieras que te de el mensaje. Si quieres que te de el nombre del objeto que generó el evento, o alguna de sus propiedades... pues tendrás que acceder a esa propiedad e introducirla en el return. Como no indicas tampoco qué es lo que quieres sacar exactamente, no te puedo ayudar más.

También puedes hacer un return según alguna condición, como por ejemplo, si fue un botón sacar un mensaje, si fue un textField sacar otro mensaje... a saber qué es lo que quieres sacar exactamente.

Comment: Nitpick. El hashcode no "es un código identificador de la posición de memoria en la que se almacena el objeto"; el javadoc es bastante claro y en ningún momento dice que deba ser eso.